# for loop for all possible combinations of letters+numbers within range

Tags: python

I need a for loop that can take an input, say of 5, and iterate through all possible 5 length combinations of uppercase/lowercase/numbers/specials and do something with each one, is this possible? I don't want to store them in memory, just iterate over them and then get rid of it.

Also how would I do just each type of char set.. letters..numbers ect..

Comment: Yes this is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried this: 'from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase
keywords = [''.join(i) for i in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat = 3)]'     but that only takes lowercase and it stores it, when doing this for like 5 length, it gets too big.

Comment: Your list comprehension `[... for i in ....]` stores the results, contrary to your request. You could either create a generator expression `(... for i in ...)`, or a loop `for i in ...:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a for loop that can take an input, say of 5, and iterate through all possible 5 length combinations of uppercase/lowercase/numbers/specials and do something with each one

For this, you might want to use `itertools.product()`

```
import string
import itertools

alphabet = string.digits + string.letters + string.punctuation

for password in itertools.product(alphabet, repeat=5):
    print ''.join(password)
```

Or, adapting the code from your comment:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
from itertools import product

keywords = (''.join(i) for i in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat = 3))
for keyword in keywords:
    print keyword
```

Comment: That is it, thanks.. however is there any way to split string.letters to lower or upper? can I replace that with ascii_lowercase and ascii_uppercase?